# Set title in dPlot / R

Tags: r, d3.js, rcharts, dimple.js

I'm trying to set a title in my dPlot using rCharts:

```
library(rCharts)

a <- data.frame(dat=0,count=0)
t <- dPlot(
  x = "dat",
  y = "count",
  data = a,
  type = "line",
  height = 400,
  width = 700,
  bounds = list(x=50,y=20,width=650,height=300)
)
t$templates$script = "http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_dimple/chartWithTitle.html"
t$set( title = "No Data found" )
t
```

Unfortunately, the suggested work around [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/229) doesn't work. Can someone help? Thanks.